# UIScrollView scrolls automatically when updating UIView inside it

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, ios5

I am in big problem. I am creating application with UITableView, where UIScrollView is inside every cell. The page control of UIScrollView is enabled and it is realized like [default example in Apple developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html).

And even if in Apple's example, everything works fine, I have problem with my program. Every time I update content of UIView that is not currently presented with UIScrollView (for example, UIScrollView is on page 1, and I update content of UIView on page 2), the UIScrollView automatically scrolls to that view (with animation). It is interesting that the scrolling stops somewhere between these two view.

So this is my code:

```
   if (controller.view.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;            
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];    
        [controller.label setText:@"some text"];     


    }
```

And if I did this in Apple's example, everything works fine, in my code (where UIScrollView is inside UITableViewCell) it scrolls automatically to some weird position.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why should you update a view which is not visible?

Comment: Becase new content must be presented in the view when user will begin scroll. It is standard procedure of Apple's paging control example.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm working on an app that has this problem on iOS5, not on iOS6....

Answer (score 0):

why because if you move the parentviewcontroller then automatically child classes also move.So again set the frame for uiscrollview

Comment: I do not understand you. I do not move parent of UIScrollView, I do not move anything. I just change the text of UILabel inside UIView inside UIScrollView. And because of that, UIScrollView automatically scrolls with animation on some undefined position.